# JPA, are query hints vendor specific?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

Are there JPA - vendor neutral - query hints that can be used ? During my google searches on query hints every mention of it has been a vendor specific query hint.

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setHint-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-):

> Set a query property or hint. The hints elements may be used to
>   specify query properties and hints. Properties defined by this
>   specification must be observed by the provider. Vendor-specific hints
>   that are not recognized by a provider must be silently ignored.
>   Portable applications should not rely on the standard timeout hint.
>   Depending on the database in use and the locking mechanisms used by
>   the provider, this hint may or may not be observed.

I'm not sure I'm understanding this correctly. Does this mean that there are vendor neutral query hints or there are not ? If so where can I find a list describing those ?

Comment: The wording is very clear. Standard hints are in the JPA spec, to be supported by all vendors. Vendor-specific hints are like it says ... vendor specific ... and ignored by any other vendor.

Comment: @NeilStockton "The wording is very clear". Isn't that subjective ? The answer I accepted also understood like me that there is NO standard hints..

Comment: There are standard hints. Here they are javax.persistence.lock.timeout, javax.persistence.query.timeout, javax.persistence.fetchgraph, javax.persistence.loadgraph. There's a pattern here .... they all start javax.persistence, and are all explicitly specified in the JPA spec

Comment: Also the ref that the "answer" uses, refers to two more relating to L2 cache interaction with queries javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode and javax.persistence.cache.shareMode. Again, they follow the same rule ... namespace defined as javax.persistence. And yes there are standard hints

Comment: @NeilStockton Well that's on me for not visiting the link. I assumed he was right. Type JPA list query hints on google and you will see all you will find is vendor specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the article found on Eclipse's website (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/concepts/queries006.htm) query hints are vendor specific.

Eclipse states that: "The definitions of query hints are vendor-specific. The following sections describe JPA query hints and EclipseLink query hints"

The article continues with specific implementation details for the two types of query hints (JPA and EclipseLink).

Further research on Apache's website (http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#jpa_hints_named) seemed to confirm that query hints are vendor specific.

Section 1.8 Query Hints...

"Hints which can not be processed by a particular database or are unknown to OpenJPA are ignored. Hints known to OpenJPA but supplied with an incompatible value will result in an IllegalArgumentException being thrown."

Based on what I've read and what you have linked in the question, I do not believe that there are "vendor-neutral" query hints. The expected behavior is that if a vendor does not support the query hint specified, it will simply be ignored.